# Asp.net: My website insist to say that my file is in use in other process

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Well, I created a site where I need to check a xml file to get some information. After read, I have to recreate the file, only changing one place, something like that:

```
public bool salvarLivro(string sCaminho, Livro liv) 
    {
        try
        {
            string sCaminhoList = sCaminho + "_listaXML.xml";
            Thread execGerarLista = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(gerarListaXml));
            List<string> parametros = new List<string>();
            parametros.Add(sCaminhoList);
            parametros.Add(liv._codigo.ToString());
            execGerarLista.Start(parametros);
            execGerarLista.Join();

            using (XmlTextWriter novoListXML = new XmlTextWriter(sCaminhoList, null)) 
            {
                novoListXML.WriteStartDocument();
                novoListXML.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                foreach (Livro li in listXml)
                {
                    novoListXML.WriteStartElement("livro");
                    novoListXML.WriteAttributeString("cod", li._codigo.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0'));
                    if (li._codigo == liv._codigo)
                    {
                        novoListXML.WriteElementString("titulo", liv._titulo);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        novoListXML.WriteElementString("titulo", li._titulo);
                    }
                    novoListXML.WriteElementString("ultModificacao", li._ultModificacao);
                    novoListXML.WriteEndElement();
                }
                novoListXML.WriteEndElement();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._sErro = ex.Message.ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }
 //to read and save information
 private void gerarListaXml(object parametros) 
    {
        //sCaminho e iCodSelec
        List<string> listParametro = (List<string>)parametros;
        string sCaminho;
        int iCodSelec;
        sCaminho = listParametro[0];
        iCodSelec = int.Parse(listParametro[1]);

        // método para retornar a lista de livros contidas em _listaXML.xml
        List<Livro> listaXml = new List<Livro>();
        Livro liv = new Livro();
        using (XmlTextReader xml = new XmlTextReader(sCaminho)) 
        {
            string sControle = "";
            while (xml.Read())
            {
                //lendo arquivo
                switch (xml.NodeType)
                {
                    //verificando nó de xml
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        switch (xml.Name)
                        {
                            case "livro":
                                liv = new Livro();
                                while (xml.MoveToNextAttribute())
                                {
                                    liv._codigo = int.Parse(xml.Value);
                                }
                                break;
                            case "titulo":
                                sControle = xml.Name;
                                break;
                            case "ultModificacao":
                                sControle = xml.Name;
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        switch (sControle)
                        {
                            //verificando nó xml anterior
                            case "titulo":
                                liv._titulo = xml.Value;
                                break;
                            case "ultModificacao":
                                if (liv._codigo == iCodSelec)
                                {
                                    liv._ultModificacao = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    liv._ultModificacao = xml.Value;
                                }
                                //adicionando liv ao listXml
                                listaXml.Add(liv);
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        listXml = listaXml;
    }
```

It's all beauty (at least for me), so start the stranger things, when I run my site everything goes as I plan, but if a stop and run again I receive a Exception:

> The process can not access the file 'F:\Escola_Tcc\LeitorGravadorXML\LeitorGravadorXML\Xml_listaXML.xml' because it is being used by another process.

The exception is catch on this line:

```
using (XmlTextWriter novoListXML = new XmlTextWriter(sCaminhoList, null))
```

Comment: What if double call the `salvarLivro()` before you stop it? and how you stop and start it?

Comment: Restart the machine - that usually clears access violations.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly calling `xml.Close()` to close the Xml reader (and underlying stream) just before the end of the `using` block in `gerarListaXml()`?  I also don't see the obvious need for your reading of the file to be started on a thread...

Comment: Where are you writing comment in file `_listaXML.xml`. Check there. It might be that you have not closed the writer and the thread is still running in background. Also, if you found this bug then restart `IIS` (to kill currently hanging thread) if you can do that or modify `web.config` file (if shared server). *Modify by adding a blank space anywhere in `web.config` and then save it.*

Comment: @ZayLau When I say that I stop and start it again, I mean that I stop running my program and run again (I'm using visual studio 12) restarting the ISS... and about double call `salvarLivro()`, on the first try its alright, runs perfectly, but when restart all, nothing work

Comment: @BrendanGreen I already tried to explicit `xml.Close()`, but didn't work. And I really don't have this necessity, but I thought that this is exception was call because my two line of codes (read and write) were running together, then I thought that use thread would ensure that this is not the problem... (This was my beginner thinking)